# How to cache larger files for development

Tags: workbox

I'm playing around with workbox but I am getting the following error:

`Skipping file 'app.js' due to size. [Max size supported is 2097152, this file is 4760833]`

I understand why it would do this in production, and this isn't a problem in production as my app.js file is minified and is well under that limit.

But how can I generate a service worker I can use in development including these larger files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes` configuration parameter, described in more detail in the docs, can be used to increase the limit.

E.g.:

```
{
  maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5000000,
  // ...other Workbox build configuration options...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I could't find this

Comment: @Jeff Posnick Can you give more details? I've been suffering with React and Workbox. I was able to put such a line in a call to workboxBuild.injectManifest and now it does not complain about my 2.1MB file, but the file still isn't cached. Does this config have to be done again with calls in the service worker?

Comment: What file is that configuration supposed to go in? What docs? A link would be nice.

Comment: @MaxWaterman you add this option in the array where you define your other workbox config options (like swSrc & swDest), e.g., in `webpack.config.js`.